# Check if existing or not in mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to insert a data to the MySQL database but before that, I'm trying to check if that data is existing or not. If not, it will insert but if yes it will show a message. 
I've run this code but it only says "Existing!" even though it doesn't exist.

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql12 = "SELECT * FROM courseandorg where connID = ?connID";
    MySqlCommand cmd12 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO courseandorg VALUES (connID, '" + lblCourseAbbrev.Text + "','" + lblOrgName.Text + "','" + lblOrgAbbrev.Text + "', '" + cboStatus.Text + "','" + txtquorum.Text + "')");  
    MySqlCommand cmd14 = new MySqlCommand(sql12, conn);
    cmd14.Parameters.AddWithValue("@connID", txtCOConnID.Text);
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd14.ExecuteScalar());    

    if (count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Existing!");
    }
    else
    {
        cmd12.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully save!");
    }

    conn.Close();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are selecting the **whole** table. If there are any records, then print Existing. Is that what you want?

Comment: You select everything. As soon as a single record exists, the function will return true. Maybe you tried to do `select count(*)`, but note that this can be very inefficient on large tables. It's better to do an `insert on duplicates ignore` statement, or an `insert .. select where not exists`. That way you have only one round trip to the database, and less risk of race conditions when others write records too.

Comment: While we're here it's also worth pointing out that your code is wide open to SQL injection.  And that your variable names are just inviting bugs and unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement has not a [where](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause so it retrieve all rows. You should filter your search so that it just check for the existing of the record that you are trying to insert:

```
string sql12 = "SELECT * FROM courseandorg where connID = @connID";
//Or I think in MySQL you should use ? instead of @ connID = ?connID"
cmd14.Parameters.AddWithValue("@connID",connIDValue);
```

Also this kind of string concatenation is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead.

Comment: I tried to run it again with the code as you said but it says "Fatal error during command execution" I update the code, take a look.

Comment: I updated the code again but it doesn't work. It says the connection must be valid and open but it is already opened and i closed it.

Comment: it says the connection must be valit and open again.

Comment: @Michelle This is why you should always use [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement.

Comment: conn.Open();
                string sql12 = "SELECT * FROM courseandorg WHERE connID = '" + txtCOConnID.Text + "'";

                MySqlCommand cmd12 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO courseandorg VALUES (connID, '" + lblCourseAbbrev.Text + "','" + lblOrgName.Text + "','" + lblOrgAbbrev.Text + "', '" + cboStatus.Text + "','" + txtquorum.Text + "')");
                
                
                MySqlCommand cmd14 = new MySqlCommand(sql12, conn);
                
              

                int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd14.ExecuteScalar());

                conn.Close();

Comment: conn.Open();
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Taken na to!");

                }
                else
                {
                    cmd12.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Save na! Yehey!");

                }

                conn.Close();
            }

Comment: catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Close();

            }

Comment: It's the same again.